# is there a solve with my python code ! return 1 only?

Tags: python

```
def check_answer (q, a, s ):
    if q == a :
        s += 1 
        print (f" your score is {s} ")
    else : 
        s -= 1 
        print (f" your score is {s} ")
```

i know maybe my english not good but i need help with my problem
i made a quiz project ,
when user enter the right answer I want the program give him more 1 point in his score
but my code does not work good !!

[image: my code return 1 only]
[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvLlq.jpg)

Comment: Incrementing/decrementing `s` in the function doesn't update the caller's variable.

Comment: Please post code as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: The function should end with `return s`. Then you can use `scoore = check_answer(Q2, A2, scoore)`

Answer (score 0):

**Two options**

1. Use return value to update caller variable
2. Use [global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function) so function uses caller's variable s

Note: Option 1 is normally preferred with Option 2 only for simple code.
Issue with Option 2 is global variables enable functions to have hidden (non-obvious, surprising, hard to detect, hard to diagnose) side effects, leading to an increase in complexity--[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)

**Option 1--use return to update s**

```
def check_answer (q, a, s ):
    # a local s is initialized to the passed-in value
    if q == a :
        s += 1                          # update local s in function check_answer
        print (f" your score is {s} ")
    else : 
        s -= 1                          # update local s in function check_answer
        print (f" your score is {s} ")
   return s   # returns the value of the local s to caller

# Usage (as mentioned by Barmar in comments)
# Initialization (set s to initial value)
s = 0
# ... some code
s = check_answer(q1, a1, s)      # s is updated to new value
# ...some more code
s = check_answer(q1, a2, s)      # s is udpated to new value
# ...and so on
```

**Option 2: share s as a global variable**

```
def check_answer (q, a):
    global s           # use s from global scope
    if q == a :
        s += 1         # updates global variable s
        print (f" your score is {s} ")
    else : 
        s -= 1         # updates global variable s
        print (f" your score is {s} ") 

# Usage
# initialize s (global scope variable i.e. outside function calls)
s = 0      
# other code
# ...
check_answer (q1, a1)   # global s is updated
# ...
#  ...
check_answer(q2, a2)   # global s is updated
# ...and so on
# ...
```